# How to give image as an user input in api request using flask in python

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

I am creating an API where I want to give image as an user input.

I know `request.args.get` take user input in dictionary format. I want to know if in any way user can give image as input to api in below api script.

My image path is `E:\env\abc.png`

a.py

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import json_normalize
from flask import request, Flask, Response
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/api_endpoint", methods=["GET"])
def function_for_api():
    
    user_input_image = request.args.get('user_input_image')
    print("USER IMAGE",user_input_image)

    status = 200
    resJson = "python_file_name output will be here in json format"
    return Response(response=resJson, status=status, mimetype="application/json")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this method should be a POST and not a GET.  You are putting information on the server.  Second, you want to read the file from the files parameter and not one of the query parameters.

```
@app.route("/api_endpoint", methods=["POST"])
def function_for_api():
    img = request.files['file']
    print(img.filename)
    return Response(status=200)
```

Here is an example of you could call this function uploading an image.

```
import requests
pic_file = "picture_filename"
# post a request with file and receive response
with open(pic_file, 'rb') as f:
    resp = requests.post(f"{your_server_address}/api_endpoint", files={'file': f})
```

Comment: Do we need to give full path of image in api request. Ex: pic_file =E:\env\abc.png

Comment: You don't need to.  You could give it a relative path from wherever your python file is being executed, but the full path is probably easiest and best.

Comment: Hi @inteoryx, your code works thanks. I want to know If I want to test `api request` using browser, how will I test??
I tried: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api_endpoint/files=linux_commands.jpg` but it's not working, can we test image api using browser??

Comment: You can test using a browser, but it's more complicated.  Remember, what your request is sending is the data, the actual bytes, of the file, not just a string in the url.  To test in the browser you need to add some HTML and Javascript to select and upload a file to your endpoint.

Comment: Hi @inteoryx, It would be great. if you share one example for testing it in browser or any references over internet. It will work!!!